# Get newly created object from List

Tags: c#

I'm automatically creating controls and I will like to add some special controls which fulfills a certain criteria to another list of controls. How can I do this? Please see within the pseudo code for comments.

```
List<Control> comboBOX;
List<Control> othercomboBOX;

    case controls.LIST:
                     comboBOX.Add(new SpecialComboBox(someparam));
                     panel.Controls.Add(comboBOX[i])

                     //Now i have this statement below:
                     if(somecondition)
                      {
                         //Take the newly created combobox which has been added to comboBOX list and add it into another list *othercomboBOX*;
                        othercomboBOX.Add(the newly created combobox)

                      }break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stick the `new SpecialComboBox` into a variable and add it to both lists.

```
List<Control> comboBOX;
List<Control> otherComboBOX;

case controls.LIST:

    ComboBox specialComboBox= new SpecialComboBox(someparam);
    comboBOX.Add(specialComboBox);
    panel.Controls.add(comboBOX[i]);

     //Now i have this statement below:
         if(somecondition) {
             //Take the newly created combobox which has been added to comboBOX list and add it into another list *othercomboBOX*;
            othercomboBOX.Add(specialComboBox);

         }break;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand correctly, you want to take your newly created `ComboBox`. So just take a combobox from `List<Control> comboBOX` using index like you did `comboBOX[i]` and add to `othercomboBox.Add(comboBox[i])`:

```
case controls.LIST:
                 comboBOX.Add(new SpecialComboBox(someparam));
                 panel.Controls.Add(comboBOX[i])

                 //Now i have this statement below:
                 if(somecondition)
                  {
                     //Take the newly created combobox which has been added to comboBOX list and add it into another list *othercomboBOX*;
                    othercomboBOX.Add(comboBOX[i])

                  }break;
```